# How to use OS patch management for compute instances with Google container optimized os?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, operating-system, google-compute-engine, patch, google-container-optimized-os

According to [GCP](https://cloud.google.com/docs/overview)'s OS patch management, patch jobs can be created for the [Compute Instance VMs](https://cloud.google.com/compute) that have the [OS config agent](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/view-os-details#install-agent) installed in them.

[This document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/manage-os#agent-install) explains how to install the agent if it is not there already in some VMs.
Operating systems it covers are:
Windows Server / Ubuntu / Debian / RHEL / CentOS SLES / openSUSE

How to create a patch job for compute instances with Google container optimized os (COS)?

I am not able to find a way to install the [OS config agent](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/view-os-details#install-agent) in these COS instances neither an option to create a "OS Patch Deployment". Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Unfortunately, you're not able to use [OS patch management](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/os-patch-management) for VM instances with [Google Container Optimized OS](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os)**.

Please have a look at the documentation [Creating patch jobs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/os-patch-management/create-patch-job) section [Supported operating systems](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/os-patch-management/create-patch-job#supported_operating_systems):

> - Debian 9
> - Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04
> - CentOS 6, 7, and 8
> - Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 6, 7, and 8
> - Windows Server 2012R2, 2016, 2019, and semi-annual releases 1803 and 1809
> - SUSE Enterprise Linux Server (SLES) 12 and 15, openSUSE Leap 15

Also, at section [Setting up your VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/os-patch-management/create-patch-job#setup-vm):

> To use the OS patch management service, you need to set up the OS
>   Config service API and install the OS Config agent. For detailed
>   instructions, see [Managing your operating systems](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/manage-os).

and as you can see at the documentation [Managing your operating systems](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/manage-os) section [Installing the OS Config agent](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/manage-os#agent-install) there's no option for Google COS.

You can try to file a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) at [Google Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) if you need this feature.

Comment: Yes, even in the options while creating a Deployment patch, there was no option to select Container Optimized OS. Thank you for confirming. I will create a feature request and post it in the question.